# CountVectorizer: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, text-classification

I have a one-dimensional array with large strings in each of the elements. I am trying to use a `CountVectorizer` to convert text data into numerical vectors. However, I am getting an error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

`mealarray` contains large strings in each of the elements. There are 5000 such samples. I am trying to vectorize this as given below:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(
    stop_words='english',
    ngram_range=(1, 1),  #ngram_range=(1, 1) is the default
    dtype='double',
)
data = vectorizer.fit_transform(mealarray)
```

The full stacktrace :

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 817, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 748, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 234, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 200, in <lambda>
    return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Someone (without having the full stack trace, it's hard to tell who, either scikit or Numpy) is trying to treat a Numpy array as a string (`"FOO".lower()` returns `"foo"`). Are you sure `mealarray`'s contents are strings, or that `CountVectorizer` wants an array of strings?

Comment: @AhmedFasih, just added full stack trace to the question !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got the answer to my question.
Basically, CountVectorizer is taking lists (with string contents) as an argument rather than array. That solved my problem.

Comment: Hi @ashu , can you please share the changes that you had made in the code. If incase you have that.

Comment: That's close, but not exactly: it has to be a one-dimensional array/list

Comment: self accepting your own answer without providing a complete explanation

Answer (score 24):

Check the shape of `mealarray`.  If the argument to [`fit_transform`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit_transform) is an array of strings, it must be a one-dimensional array. (That is, `mealarray.shape` must be of the form `(n,)`.)  For example, you'll get the "no attribute" error if `mealarray` has a shape such as `(n, 1)`.

You could try something like

```
data = vectorizer.fit_transform(mealarray.ravel())
```

Comment: I tried it with ravel and got the following error. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'.                           The shape of mealarray is (5000,1) because I created it using "mealarray = np.empty((plen,1), dtype=object)"

Comment: OK, so you then populate the array afterwards.  Then you must have a count of the actual number of words in `mealarray`, correct?  Let's say it is `nwords`.  Then pass `mealarray[:nwords].ravel()` to `fit_transform()`.  (Although I wonder why you create the array with shape `(plen,1)` instead of just `(plen,)`.)

Comment: Note: In my previous comment, I assume that you fill `mealarray` from the beginning, with no indices containing `None` between indices containing words.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser had similar problem, your `ravel()` solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A better solution is explicit call pandas series and pass it CountVectorizer():

```
>>> tex = df4['Text']
>>> type(tex)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(tex)
```

Next one won't work, cause its a frame and NOT series

```
>>> tex2 = (df4.ix[0:,[11]])
>>> type(tex2)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error:

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'`

To solve this problem, I did the following:

1. Verify the dimension of the array with:
   `name_of_array1.shape`
2. I output is: (n,1) then use `flatten()` to convert an array of two-dimensional to one-dimensional:
   `flat_array = name_of_array1.flatten()`
3. Now, I can use `CountVectorizer()` because this works with list of one argument as a string.