# Received AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower' with permutation_importance

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to use [permutation_importance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance.html) to calculate feature importance. From the doc, I understood that X_train needs to be array, and y_train needs to be array-like. However, I received `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'`

My code

```
vectoriser = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,3), norm=None)
X_train = vectoriser.fit_transform(df['x'])
X_train = np.nan_to_num(X_train).toarray()
y_train = df['y']
y_train = y_train.values

# Undersampling
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=0)
X_train, y_train = rus.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)

# Load the saved model
clf = joblib.load('model.joblib')

# Calculate result --> triggered error
result = permutation_importance(clf, X_train, y_train, n_repeats=10, random_state=42)
```

The data

X_train.  shape = (1068, 3528)

```
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

y_train.  shape = (1068,)

```
array(['A', 'A', 'A', ..., 'B', 'B', 'B'],
      dtype=object)
```

I input the correct data type why it gives me this error. Also what's does the error mean ?
Thanks

Comment: in which line the error occurs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367075/countvectorizer-attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-lower

Comment: the result line @PV8

Comment: Does the linked thread above answers your question?

Comment: @desertnaut No, I input the correct data type and shape. I came through that post previously for research already.